# Disable chrome 73 from intercepting media keys

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Chrome 73 [introduced a feature](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/02/08/google-chrome-73-to-support-multimedia-keys-on-the-keyboard/) that allows sites like youtube and netflix to intercept the play/pause button on my keyboard. I don't want to use it like this, because it stops spotify from listening to that key and it plays or pauses even if the tab with the video isn't selected.

I looked through the settings menu and I can't see a way to disable it, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way that works, go to chrome://flags/ and search Media Keys. Instead of having it be set to Default. Change it to Disabled. That should work. I can't know for sure since I just did it myself, but it's worth a try

Comment: That worked! Thank you

Comment: The specific item to look for is "Hardware Media Key Handling" and yes it does work. This URL should bring you to it: chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling